# How to add button in layout view (grid control)in dev express

Tags: c#, devexpress

hii,

Can anyone please answer how to add button in a layout view in dev express.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the column's ColumnEdit property to an instance of the RepositoryItemButtonEdit class.  This will force the grid to show an editor and a button close to it.  To hide this editor, set the [RepositoryItemButtonEdit.TextEditStyle](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemButtonEdit_TextEditStyletopic) to the HideTextEditor value.